# asp:FileUpload losing selected file on PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a asp:Fileupload control on my page.

After this control I have some checkboxes which fires checked changed event,

But when the checked changed event is fired or any of the postback occurs due to any reason, asp:Fileupload loses its selected file.

How can I stop this ?
as I am not using any Update Panel this question is different from others

Here is my aspx code :

```
 <tr>
                         <td><b>Attach CNIC :</b></td>
                         <td><asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="file_nominee" /></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                         <td><b>Enter Share Percentage(s)</b></td>
                         <td>
                        <asp:Table ID="tbl_fundtype" runat="server" CssClass="table-bordered tblfund" style="width:50%; white-space:nowrap;">
                        </asp:Table>
                         </td>
                     </tr>
```

Comment: The page is refreshed so control will be reinitialized.

Comment: @MairajAhmad how should I prevent this

Comment: I am not sure but i think you can't do this.